# java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground() parsing data

Tags: java, android

I have been looking for an answer here because i see others had the same problem. An error occured while executing doInBackground, but i couldn't find a solution for my problem here.

Here is the error:

```
    07-07 15:56:30.060: E/AndroidRuntime(26940): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
07-07 15:56:30.060: E/AndroidRuntime(26940): Process: com.dusandimitrijevic.filmovipreporuke, PID: 26940
07-07 15:56:30.060: E/AndroidRuntime(26940): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
07-07 15:56:30.060: E/AndroidRuntime(26940):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
07-07 15:56:30.060: E/AndroidRuntime(26940):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
07-07 15:56:30.060: E/AndroidRuntime(26940):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
07-07 15:56:30.060: E/AndroidRuntime(26940):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
07-07 15:56:30.060: E/AndroidRuntime(26940):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
07-07 15:56:30.060: E/AndroidRuntime(26940):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
07-07 15:56:30.060: E/AndroidRuntime(26940):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
07-07 15:56:30.060: E/AndroidRuntime(26940):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
07-07 15:56:30.060: E/AndroidRuntime(26940): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.io.File com.parse.ParsePlugins.getParseDir()' on a null object reference
07-07 15:56:30.060: E/AndroidRuntime(26940):    at com.parse.Parse.getParseDir(Parse.java:304)
07-07 15:56:30.060: E/AndroidRuntime(26940):    at com.parse.ParseObject.getFromDisk(ParseObject.java:667)
07-07 15:56:30.060: E/AndroidRuntime(26940):    at com.parse.ParseUser$10.then(ParseUser.java:1056)
07-07 15:56:30.060: E/AndroidRuntime(26940):    at com.parse.ParseUser$10.then(ParseUser.java:1003)
07-07 15:56:30.060: E/AndroidRuntime(26940):    at bolts.Task$14.run(Task.java:796)
07-07 15:56:30.060: E/AndroidRuntime(26940):    at bolts.BoltsExecutors$ImmediateExecutor.execute(BoltsExecutors.java:105)
07-07 15:56:30.060: E/AndroidRuntime(26940):    at bolts.Task.completeAfterTask(Task.java:787)
07-07 15:56:30.060: E/AndroidRuntime(26940):    at bolts.Task.continueWithTask(Task.java:599)
07-07 15:56:30.060: E/AndroidRuntime(26940):    at bolts.Task.continueWithTask(Task.java:610)
07-07 15:56:30.060: E/AndroidRuntime(26940):    at com.parse.ParseUser.getCurrentUserAsync(ParseUser.java:1003)
07-07 15:56:30.060: E/AndroidRuntime(26940):    at com.parse.ParseUser.access$800(ParseUser.java:26)
07-07 15:56:30.060: E/AndroidRuntime(26940):    at com.parse.ParseUser$9.then(ParseUser.java:996)
07-07 15:56:30.060: E/AndroidRuntime(26940):    at com.parse.ParseUser$9.then(ParseUser.java:993)
07-07 15:56:30.060: E/AndroidRuntime(26940):    at com.parse.TaskQueue.enqueue(TaskQueue.java:61)
07-07 15:56:30.060: E/AndroidRuntime(26940):    at com.parse.ParseUser.getCurrentUserAsync(ParseUser.java:993)
07-07 15:56:30.060: E/AndroidRuntime(26940):    at com.parse.ParseUser.getCurrentUserAsync(ParseUser.java:956)
07-07 15:56:30.060: E/AndroidRuntime(26940):    at com.parse.ParseQuery.getUserAsync(ParseQuery.java:914)
07-07 15:56:30.060: E/AndroidRuntime(26940):    at com.parse.ParseQuery$3.call(ParseQuery.java:1172)
07-07 15:56:30.060: E/AndroidRuntime(26940):    at com.parse.ParseQuery$3.call(ParseQuery.java:1169)
07-07 15:56:30.060: E/AndroidRuntime(26940):    at com.parse.ParseQuery.doWithRunningCheck(ParseQuery.java:1108)
07-07 15:56:30.060: E/AndroidRuntime(26940):    at com.parse.ParseQuery.findAsync(ParseQuery.java:1169)
07-07 15:56:30.060: E/AndroidRuntime(26940):    at com.parse.ParseQuery.findInBackground(ParseQuery.java:1137)
07-07 15:56:30.060: E/AndroidRuntime(26940):    at com.parse.ParseQuery.find(ParseQuery.java:957)
07-07 15:56:30.060: E/AndroidRuntime(26940):    at com.dusandimitrijevic.filmovipreporuke.MainActivity$RemoteDataTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:68)
07-07 15:56:30.060: E/AndroidRuntime(26940):    at com.dusandimitrijevic.filmovipreporuke.MainActivity$RemoteDataTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
07-07 15:56:30.060: E/AndroidRuntime(26940):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
07-07 15:56:30.060: E/AndroidRuntime(26940):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
07-07 15:56:30.060: E/AndroidRuntime(26940):    ... 4 more
07-07 15:56:32.002: I/Choreographer(26940): Skipped 96 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-07 15:56:32.162: E/OpenGLRenderer(26940): SFEffectCache:clear(), mSize = 0
07-07 15:56:32.222: E/WindowManager(26940): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.dusandimitrijevic.filmovipreporuke.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{34b0c646 V.E..... R......D 0,0-1002,475} that was originally added here
07-07 15:56:32.222: E/WindowManager(26940):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:465)
07-07 15:56:32.222: E/WindowManager(26940):     at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:277)
07-07 15:56:32.222: E/WindowManager(26940):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
07-07 15:56:32.222: E/WindowManager(26940):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:312)
07-07 15:56:32.222: E/WindowManager(26940):     at com.dusandimitrijevic.filmovipreporuke.MainActivity$RemoteDataTask.onPreExecute(MainActivity.java:55)
07-07 15:56:32.222: E/WindowManager(26940):     at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:587)
07-07 15:56:32.222: E/WindowManager(26940):     at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:535)
07-07 15:56:32.222: E/WindowManager(26940):     at com.dusandimitrijevic.filmovipreporuke.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:30)
07-07 15:56:32.222: E/WindowManager(26940):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6289)
07-07 15:56:32.222: E/WindowManager(26940):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
07-07 15:56:32.222: E/WindowManager(26940):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
07-07 15:56:32.222: E/WindowManager(26940):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2758)
07-07 15:56:32.222: E/WindowManager(26940):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
07-07 15:56:32.222: E/WindowManager(26940):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1448)
07-07 15:56:32.222: E/WindowManager(26940):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-07 15:56:32.222: E/WindowManager(26940):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
07-07 15:56:32.222: E/WindowManager(26940):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942)
07-07 15:56:32.222: E/WindowManager(26940):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
07-07 15:56:32.222: E/WindowManager(26940):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
07-07 15:56:32.222: E/WindowManager(26940):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400)
07-07 15:56:32.222: E/WindowManager(26940):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)
```

Here is the code from MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends MyActionBar {

ListView listView;
List<ParseObject> ob;
ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
ListViewAdapter adapter;
private List<Filmovi> naslov = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    new RemoteDataTask().execute();
}

@Override
protected int getLayoutResourceId() {
    return R.layout.activity_main;


}



// RemoteDataTask AsyncTask
    private class RemoteDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Create a progressdialog
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            // Set progressdialog title
            mProgressDialog.setTitle("Horor Filmovi - Analize i Ocene");
            // Set progressdialog message
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Ucitavanje...");
            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            // Show progressdialog
            mProgressDialog.show();
        }
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // Create the array
            naslov = new ArrayList<Filmovi>();
            try {
                // Locate the class table named "Film" in Parse.com
                ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>(
                        "Film");
                // Locate the column named "ranknum" in Parse.com and order list
                // by ascending
                query.orderByAscending("ranknum");
                ob = query.find();
                for (ParseObject ime : ob) {
                    // Locate images in slike column
                    ParseFile image = (ParseFile) ime.get("slika");

                    Filmovi map = new Filmovi();
                    map.setIme((String) ime.get("naslov"));
                    map.setSlika(image.getUrl());
                    naslov.add(map);
                }
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // Locate the listview in listview_main.xml
            listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
            // Pass the results into ListViewAdapter.java
            adapter = new ListViewAdapter(MainActivity.this,
                    naslov);
            // Binds the Adapter to the ListView
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            // Close the progressdialog
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }

    }
}
```

Here is the initialization:

```
public class ParseApplication extends Application {


@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    // Add your initialization code here
    Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);
    Parse.initialize(this, "MY IDENTIFICATION ID", "CLIENT KEY");

    ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();
    ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();

    // If you would like all objects to be private by default, remove,this line.
    defaultACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);

    ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, true);
}


}
```

Anyone know what is the problem here?

Comment: This sounds important `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.io.File com.parse.ParsePlugins.getParseDir()' on a null object reference`

Comment: What is on `MainActivity.java:68`?

Comment: @AniketThakur to complement you comment `at com.dusandimitrijevic.filmovipreporuke.MainActivity$RemoteDataTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:68)`

Comment: @AniketThakur ob = query.find();

Comment: Add print your objects in doinbackground. Some object is null. find it out

Comment: Somewhere in this workflow you are calling `ParseObject.getFromDisk` that internally calling `getParseDir()` method on a `Parse` object that is null. Check how you are constructing that `Parse` object.

Comment: Have you initialize your parse object ?

Comment: I have editet my question. There you can see my initilazition.